# Permission Settings Help

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, permissions

I have a bit of an odd question on debugging a new LWC. I recently added functionality to an existing component, however now that the new functionality is in place the permissions seem to be a bit off even though the profiles seem to have the same permissions. The field in question is labeled as SMS_Permission. This field is viewable and editable, however this is the message I get on the debug logs,

**Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0038W00001s6U63QAE; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You cannot change the SMS Permission to "Not Asked" or Blank from a different value.: [SMS_Permission__c]**

It seems to try to enter a blank value into the field if you are using any profile except for System Admin. Any Ideas? I'll leave my apex just in case.

```
public with sharing class PhoneManagementController {
    @TestVisible private static List<String> badPhoneReasons {
        get {
            if (badPhoneReasons == null) {
                badPhoneReasons = new List<String>();
                for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklistEntry : Schema.SObjectType.Bad_Phone__c.fields.Reason__c.getPicklistValues()) {
                    badPhoneReasons.add(picklistEntry.getValue());
                }
            }
            return badPhoneReasons;
        }
        set;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> typePicklistValueByPhoneType = new Map<String, String>{
            'Phone' => 'Office', 'HomePhone' => 'Home', 'MobilePhone' => 'Mobile', 'Farm_Shop_Phone__c' => 'Farm/Shop'
    };

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getBestPhone(String ContactId)
    {
        Bad_Phone__c[] PhoneHistoryRecords = [SELECT Contact__c, Reason__c, Type__c, Phone_Status__c FROM Bad_Phone__c WHERE Contact__c = :contactId];
        integer[] sucessArr = new List<integer> {0,0,0,0};
        String BestPhone = 'Error';

        for(Bad_Phone__c record: PhoneHistoryRecords)
        {
            if(record.Phone_Status__c == 'Verified' || record.Phone_Status__c == 'Reached')
            {
                switch on record.Type__c
                {
                    when 'Mobile'{sucessArr[0]++;}
                    when 'Home'{sucessArr[1]++;}
                    when 'Office'{sucessArr[2]++;}
                    when 'Farm/Shop'{sucessArr[3]++;}
                }
            }
        }

        integer[] sortedList = new List<integer>{};
        for(integer item : sucessArr)
            sortedList.add(item);
        sortedList.sort();
        
        if(sortedList[3] == 0)
            return 'Null';

        switch on sucessArr.indexOf(sortedList[3])
        {
            when 0{BestPhone = 'Mobile';}
            when 1{BestPhone = 'Home';}
            when 2{BestPhone = 'Office';}
            when 3{BestPhone = 'Farm/Shop';}
        }
        return BestPhone;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void editPhone(PhoneWrapper phoneWrapper) {
        phoneWrapper.validate();
        Contact contact = [SELECT Id, Phone, HomePhone, MobilePhone, Farm_Shop_Phone__c, Fax, SMS_Permission__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :phoneWrapper.contactId Limit 1];
        
        List <Project_Contact__c> projectContact = [SELECT Id, Mobile_Status__c, Mobile_Status_Date_Time__c, Home_Status__c, Home_Status_Date_Time__c, Office_Status__c, 
        Office_Status_Date_Time__c, Farm_Shop_Status__c, Farm_Shop_Status_Date_Time__c FROM Project_Contact__c WHERE Id = :phoneWrapper.PCID LIMIT 1];

        if((phoneWrapper.reason == 'Wrong' || phoneWrapper.reason == 'Disconnected' 
        || phoneWrapper.reason == 'Temporarily Disconnected') && !String.isBlank(phoneWrapper.newNo))
        {
            insert new Bad_Phone__c (
                    Contact__c = contact.Id,
                    Phone_Number__c = phoneWrapper.newNo,
                    Reason__c = 'New',
                    Type__c = typePicklistValueByPhoneType.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType),
                    Phone_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus
            );
        }
        if(phoneWrapper.reason == 'addNew' && phoneWrapper.newNo == null){
            throw new AuraHandledException('No New Number Was Provided');
        }
        else if ((badPhoneReasons.contains(phoneWrapper.reason) || phoneWrapper.reason == 'addNew')) {
            insert new Bad_Phone__c (
                    Contact__c = contact.Id,
                    Phone_Number__c = phoneWrapper.reason == 'addNew' ? phoneWrapper.newNo : (String) contact.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType),
                    Reason__c = phoneWrapper.reason == 'addNew' ? 'New' : phoneWrapper.reason,
                    Type__c = typePicklistValueByPhoneType.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType),
                    Phone_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus
            );
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.phoneType, phoneWrapper.newNo);
            update contact;
        } 
        else if((!String.isBlank(phoneWrapper.phoneStatus)) && String.isBlank(phoneWrapper.reason))
        {
            insert new Bad_Phone__c (
                Contact__c = contact.Id,
                Phone_Number__c = phoneWrapper.reason == 'addNew' ? phoneWrapper.newNo : (String) contact.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType),
                Reason__c = phoneWrapper.reason == 'addNew' ? 'New' : phoneWrapper.reason,
                Type__c = typePicklistValueByPhoneType.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType),
                Phone_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus
        );
        }   
        else if (phoneWrapper.reason == 'moveTo') {
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.moveSwapType, contact.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType));
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.phoneType, null);
            update contact;
        } else if (phoneWrapper.reason == 'moveFrom') {
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.phoneType, contact.get(phoneWrapper.moveSwapType));
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.moveSwapType, null);
            update contact;
        } else if (phoneWrapper.reason == 'swapWith') {
            String tmpPhoneNo = (String)contact.get(phoneWrapper.phoneType);
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.phoneType, contact.get(phoneWrapper.moveSwapType));
            contact.put(phoneWrapper.moveSwapType, tmpPhoneNo);
            update contact;
        }
        if(contact.SMS_Permission__c != phoneWrapper.smsPermission && phoneWrapper.smsPermission != null){
            contact.SMS_Permission__c = phoneWrapper.smsPermission;
            update contact;
        }
        if(!String.isBlank(phoneWrapper.phoneStatus) && projectContact.size() > 0)
        {
            switch on (phoneWrapper.phoneKind)
            {
                when ('Mobile Phone'){
                    projectContact.get(0).Mobile_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus;
                    projectContact.get(0).Mobile_Status_Date_Time__c = DateTime.now();
                }
                when ('Home Phone'){
                    projectContact.get(0).Home_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus;
                    projectContact.get(0).Home_Status_Date_Time__c = DateTime.now();
                }
                when ('Office Phone'){
                    projectContact.get(0).Office_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus;
                    projectContact.get(0).Office_Status_Date_Time__c = DateTime.now();
                }
                when ('Farm Shop Phone'){
                    projectContact.get(0).Farm_Shop_Status__c = phoneWrapper.phoneStatus;
                    projectContact.get(0).Farm_Shop_Status_Date_Time__c = DateTime.now();
                }
            }
            update projectContact.get(0);
        }
    }

    public class PhoneWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled public String contactId {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String phoneType {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String phoneKind {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String newNo {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String currentNo {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String reason {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String moveSwapType {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String smsPermission {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String PCID {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String phoneStatus {get; set;}

        public void validate() {
            if (String.isBlank(contactId)) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Contact ID Not Retrieved');
            }
        }

        public PhoneWrapper() {}
    }
}
```

Here's JS as well.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getFieldValue, getRecord, getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import editPhone from '@salesforce/apex/PhoneManagementController.editPhone';
import getBestPhone from '@salesforce/apex/PhoneManagementController.getBestPhone';

import BAD_PHONE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Bad_Phone__c';

import REASON_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Bad_Phone__c.Reason__c';

import Contact_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Contact__c.Contact_ID__c';
import CONTACT_SMS_PERMISSION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.SMS_Permission__c';
import getContactId from '@salesforce/apex/ProjectContactController.getContactId';
import ContactId from '@salesforce/schema/Case.ContactId';

export default class PhoneManagement extends LightningElement
{
    // The Official Record ID for the current Project Contact
    @api recordId;
    // Records the SMS Permission For this current Project Contact
    @track smsPermission;
    // Contains the name of the Salesforce Icon used to display on the Project Contact Page
    @track smsIcon;

    StatusDisabled = false;

    mobileColor = 'black';
    homeColor = 'black';
    officeColor = 'black';
    farmShopColor = 'black';

    // Gets the Project Contact Object with the Accociated Contact ID field as data
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [Contact_ID_FIELD] })ProjectAccount;

    /* Gets the Accociated Contact Object with the SMS Permission Field as data
       The local variable smsPermission is set to the Contacts SMS_Permission data*/
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$contactId', fields: [CONTACT_SMS_PERMISSION_FIELD] })
    wiredRecord({ data, error })
    {
        if (data)
        {
            this.smsPermission = data.fields.SMS_Permission__c.value;
            this.smsIcon = this.iconSetter(this.smsPermission);
        }
        else if (error)
        {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getBestPhone, { ContactId: '$contactId'})
    wiredPhone(result)
    {
        if(result.data)
            this.bestPhoneSetter(result.data);
        else if(result.error)
        {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result.error));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Unknown error',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Project_Contact__c.Contact__r.Id', 'Project_Contact__c.Contact__r.HomePhone',
     'Project_Contact__c.Contact__r.Phone', 'Project_Contact__c.Contact__r.MobilePhone', 'Project_Contact__c.Contact__r.Farm_Shop_Phone__c',
      'Project_Contact__c.Contact__r.Fax', 'Project_Contact__c.SMS_Permission__c'] })
    wiredPC({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.contact = data.fields.Contact__r.value.fields;
            this.isContactFetched = true;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Contact error',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: BAD_PHONE_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: REASON_FIELD})
    reasonPicklistValues({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.reasonPicklistValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.values));
            this.isReasonOptionsFetched = true;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Unknown error',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }

    @track contact = {
        Id: ''
    };
    @track isContactFetched = false;
    @track isReasonOptionsFetched = false;
    @track editPhoneModal = false;
    @track isSaving = false;
    @track phoneType = '';
    @track phoneKind = '';
    @track incorrectNoField = '';
    @track newNo = '';
    @track reason = '';
    @track phoneStatus = '';
    @track smsPermission = '';
    @track reasonPicklistValues = [];
    @track reasonOptions = [];
    @track phoneStatusOptions = [];
    @track smsPermissionOptions = [];
    @track moveSwapLabel = '';
    @track moveSwapType = '';
    @track moveSwapPhoneOptions = [];

    phoneFieldToLabelMapping = {
        HomePhone: 'Home',
        Phone: 'Office',
        MobilePhone: 'Mobile',
        Farm_Shop_Phone__c: 'Farm Shop',
        Fax: 'Fax'
    }

    // Sets the Icon next to the Mobile phone to the respective field
    iconSetter(smsPermission)
    {
        if(smsPermission == 'Opt In')
            return "action:approval";
        else if(smsPermission == 'Opt Out')
            return "action:close";
        else if(smsPermission == 'Reminder Only')
            return "action:priority";
        else
            return "action:info";
    }

    bestPhoneSetter(bestPhone)
    {
        switch(bestPhone)
        {
            case 'Mobile':
                this.mobileColor = 'green';
                break;
            case 'Home':
                this.homeColor = 'green';
                break;
            case 'Office':
                this.officeColor = 'green';
                break;
            case 'Farm/Shop':
                this.farmShopColor = 'green';
                break;
        }
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.editPhoneModal = false;
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.reason = '';
        this.newNo = '';
        this.phoneStatus = '';
    }

    onEditPhoneClick(event) {
        this.newNo = '';
        this.phoneType = this.phoneFieldToLabelMapping[event.target.dataset.id] + ' Phone';
        this.phoneKind = this.phoneType;
        this.incorrectNoField = event.target.dataset.id;
        this.prepareOptions();
        this.StatusDisabled = false;
        this.editPhoneModal = true;
    }

    prepareOptions() {
        this.reasonOptions = [];
        if (this.contact[this.incorrectNoField].value) {
            this.reasonOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.reasonPicklistValues));
            this.reasonOptions.push({label: 'Move To', value: 'moveTo'});
            this.reasonOptions.push({label: 'Move From', value: 'moveFrom'});
            this.reasonOptions.push({label: 'Swap With', value: 'swapWith'});
        } else {
            this.reasonOptions.push({label: 'Add New', value: 'addNew'});
            this.reasonOptions.push({label: 'Move From', value: 'moveFrom'});
            this.reason = 'addNew';
        }

        this.phoneStatusOptions = [];
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Voicemail - Left Message', value: 'Voicemail – Left Message'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Voicemail – No Message', value: 'Voicemail – No Message'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Generic Voicemail – Left Message', value: 'Generic Voicemail – Left Message'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Generic Voicemail – No Message', value: 'Generic Voicemail – No Message'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Left Message – Person', value: 'Left Message – Person'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Call Back Day', value: 'Call Back Day'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Call Back Night', value: 'Call Back Night'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Reached', value: 'Reached'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Verified', value: 'Verified'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'No Answer', value: 'No Answer'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Hang Up', value: 'Hang Up'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Blocked Call', value: 'Blocked Call'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Busy Signal', value: 'Busy Signal'});
        this.phoneStatusOptions.push({label: 'Fast Busy Signal', value: 'Fast Busy Signal'});

        this.smsPermissionOptions = [];
        this.smsPermissionOptions.push({label: 'Opt In', value: 'Opt In'});
        this.smsPermissionOptions.push({label: 'Opt Out', value: 'Opt Out'});
        this.smsPermissionOptions.push({label: 'Reminder Only', value: 'Reminder Only'});
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        switch (event.target.dataset.id) {
          case 'reasonPicklist':
            this.reason = event.target.value;
            this.moveSwapType = '';
            if (this.checkReasonValidity() && this.checkIfReasonIsMoveSwapType()) {
                this.prepareMoveSwapOptions();
                this.moveSwapLabel = event.target.options.find(option => option.value === event.target.value).label;
            }
            break;
          case 'moveSwapPicklist':
            this.moveSwapType = event.target.value;
            break;
          case 'newNo':
            this.newNo = event.target.value;
            break;
          case 'smsPermission':
            this.smsPermission = event.target.value;
            break;
          case 'phoneStatus':
            this.phoneStatus = event.target.value;
            break;
        }

        if(this.reason == 'moveTo' || this.reason == 'swapWith')
            this.StatusDisabled = true;
        else
            this.StatusDisabled = false;
    }

    editPhone() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        editPhone({
            phoneWrapper: {
                contactId: this.contact.Id.value,
                phoneType: this.incorrectNoField,
                phoneKind: this.phoneKind,
                newNo: this.newNo,
                reason: this.reason,
                moveSwapType: this.moveSwapType,
                smsPermission: this.smsPermission,
                PCID: this.recordId,
                phoneStatus: this.phoneStatus
            }
        })
        .then(() =>
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Phone has been changed successfully!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.contact.Id.value}]);
            this.closeModal();
        })
        .then(r => 
        {
            refreshApex(this.ProjectAccount).catch(error => console.error(error));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            console.error(error);
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error during save.',
                    message: (error.body) ? error.body.message : JSON.stringify(error),
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
            this.closeModal();
        });
    }

    checkIfReasonIsPossible() {
        return ((this.reason === 'moveFrom' || this.reason === 'addNew') && !this.contact[this.incorrectNoField].value) || ((this.reason !== 'moveFrom' && this.reason !== 'addNew') && this.contact[this.incorrectNoField].value);
    }

    checkReasonValidity(type) {
        let reasonPicklist = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="reasonPicklist"]');
        if (this.checkIfReasonIsPossible()) {
            reasonPicklist.setCustomValidity('');
            reasonPicklist.reportValidity();
            return true;
        }
        let validityReason = 'Selected Phone # <option> be empty to use this option.';
        reasonPicklist.setCustomValidity((this.reason === 'moveFrom' ? validityReason.replace('<option>', 'must') : validityReason.replace('<option>', 'can\'t')));
        reasonPicklist.reportValidity();
        return false
    }

    prepareMoveSwapOptions() {
        this.moveSwapPhoneOptions = [];
        for (const fieldName in this.phoneFieldToLabelMapping) {
            if (this.incorrectNoField !== fieldName) {
                let phoneNo = this.formatPhone(this.contact[fieldName].value);
                if (!phoneNo && this.reason === 'moveTo') {
                    this.moveSwapPhoneOptions.push({label: this.phoneFieldToLabelMapping[fieldName], value: fieldName});
                } else if (phoneNo && this.reason !== 'moveTo') {
                    this.moveSwapPhoneOptions.push({label: this.phoneFieldToLabelMapping[fieldName] + ' ' + phoneNo, value: fieldName});
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.moveSwapPhoneOptions.length) {
            this.moveSwapType = this.moveSwapPhoneOptions[0].value;
        }
    }

    formatPhone(phoneNo) {
        if (phoneNo) {
            let formattedPhoneNo = phoneNo.replace(/\D+/g, '');
            if (formattedPhoneNo.length === 10) {
                return '(' + formattedPhoneNo.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + formattedPhoneNo.substring(3, 6) + '-' + formattedPhoneNo.substring(6, 10);
            }
        }
        return phoneNo;
    }

    checkIfReasonIsMoveSwapType() {
        if (this.reason === 'moveTo' || this.reason === 'moveFrom' || this.reason === 'swapWith') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    get isSpinnerOn() {
        return !(this.isContactFetched && this.isReasonOptionsFetched);
    }

    get saveButtonDisabled() {
        return this.isSaving || !(this.checkIfReasonIsPossible() && this.reason && (!this.checkIfReasonIsMoveSwapType() || this.checkIfReasonIsMoveSwapType() && this.moveSwapType));
    }

    get showMoveSwapPicklist() {
        return this.checkIfReasonIsMoveSwapType() && this.checkIfReasonIsPossible();
    }

    get disableMoveSwapPicklist() {
        return !this.moveSwapPhoneOptions.length;
    }

    get incorrectNoExists() {
        return this.contact[this.incorrectNoField].value;
    }

    get isNewNoVisible() {
        return !this.checkIfReasonIsMoveSwapType() || this.reason === 'addNew';
    }

    get contactId()
    {
        return getFieldValue(this.ProjectAccount.data, Contact_ID_FIELD);
    }

    get isMobile()
    {
        return this.phoneKind === 'Mobile Phone';
    }

    get displayNewNo()
    {
        return (this.reason === 'addNew' || this.reason === 'Wrong'|| this.reason === 'Disconnected' || this.reason === 'Temporarily Disconnected');
    }

    get newNoLabel()
    {
        if (this.reason === 'Wrong'|| this.reason === 'Disconnected' || this.reason === 'Temporarily Disconnected')
        {
            return 'New # (Optional)';
        }
        return 'New #';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` can only come from two places: Apex and Validation Rules. First, check ⚙️ | Setup | Object Manager | Contacts | Validation Rules, and see if there are any rules defined here, and what they do. If you don't find it there, it's in code somewhere. I'd recommend using the Developer Console (⚙️ | Developer Console), then use the Edit | Search in Files for the phrase `"You cannot change the SMS Permission"` (with quotes for accuracy), and you should find the logic behind it.

Alternatively, you can open the Developer Console, run your code, and then check the Logs tab in the lower-left corner. Double-click to open the log, then search for the `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` string in the filter box. This should bring up the lines involved with this error, and you can start reading backwards to find the class or trigger that is generating this error. There will be quite a lot of log to read though, but a few simple searches should help find the cause.

Comment: Thank you, I understand why the validation rule is being triggered. The validation rule states that the field cannot be changed to "Not Asked" or ISBLANK when the field SMS_Permission__c field already contains a value. The root of the problem however is that the smsPermission is being set to blank if you are not a System Admin. Thus triggering the validation rule. Do you happen to see anything within the code that would point to why this may be? Thank you for your time

Comment: @JLadage If I had to guess, this is a Field Level Security problem, actually. You're using `getRecord`, which will return an error if there's any inaccessible fields. Check your Developer Console log in the browser for the error to confirm. The solution, if this is the problem, is to fix Field Level Security for those profiles.

Comment: Thank you, The other profiles ended up not having access to 'Contact ID'. A bit hard to diagnose, but with JS debug statements it was relatively easy. Thank you for your time.